# Installing Multi2sim

Tags: 18.04, 22.04

does anyone here knows how to install Multi2sim on Ubuntu 18.04 or 22.04? I am having hard time and always stuck in the cmake part. Thank you so much.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.